# "Using generic type 'Func<TResult>' requires 1 type arguments" issue when defining a delegate function type with more than 4 arguments

Tags: c#, first-class-functions

I receiving the following error: `"Using generic type 'Func<TResult>' requires 1 type arguments". It occurs when I attempt to define a dictionary which maps strings to delegate functions.`

The dictionary looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> builtInFunctions = new Dictionary<string, Func<Expression, Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, Value>, Dictionary<string, Token>, Dictionary<string, Cube>, Result>>()
{
    {"ToString", ToString}
};

Result ToString(
    Expression expression,
    Dictionary<string, string> env, 
    Dictionary<string, Value> store, 
    ref Dictionary<string, Token> tokenEnv, 
    ref Dictionary<string, Cube> cubeEnv
) {
    // implemented ToString function
}
```

And the error is occurring on this partof the code:

```
Func<Expression, Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, Value>, Dictionary<string, Token>, Dictionary<string, Cube>, Result>
```

And it still appears if I use different simpler types for it, for instance:

```
Func<int, int, int, int, int, int>
```

Can delegate functions only take 4 arguments, or is there a way around this?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738431/cant-figure-out-how-to-resolve-with-functresult-requires-1-type-arguments

Comment: This isn't an issue of the return type not being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ToString` function mustn't have `ref` parameters.

They are not defined in your `Func` and they can't be.

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462814/func-delegate-with-ref-variable) for more insight.

You might have error in your code, because declaring a `Func` with four or five arguments shouldn't be a problem.

This code works perfectly fine with me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Expression{}
public class Value{}
public class Token{}
public class Cube{}
public class Result{
    public int result = 11;
}

namespace MyNameSpace{
    using MyGenericFunc = Func<Expression, Dictionary<string, string>, Dictionary<string, Value>, Dictionary<string, Token>, Dictionary<string, Cube>, Result>;


    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Expression expression = new Expression();
            Dictionary<string, string> env = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
            Dictionary<string, Value> store = new Dictionary<string, Value>();
            Dictionary<string, Token> tokenEnv = new Dictionary<string, Token>();
            Dictionary<string, Cube> cubeEnv = new Dictionary<string, Cube>();

            // normal call
            Console.WriteLine("When calling the method directly: " + ToStringFunc(expression, env, store, tokenEnv, cubeEnv).result);

            // call via func and dictionary
            MyGenericFunc retrievedFunc;
            builtInFunctions.TryGetValue("ToString", out retrievedFunc);
            Console.WriteLine("When calling the method retrieved from dictionary: " + retrievedFunc.Invoke(expression, env, store, tokenEnv, cubeEnv).result);
        }

        static Dictionary<string, MyGenericFunc> builtInFunctions = new Dictionary<string, MyGenericFunc>()
        {
            {"ToString", ToStringFunc}
        };

        static Result ToStringFunc(
            Expression expression,
            Dictionary<string, string> env, 
            Dictionary<string, Value> store, 
            Dictionary<string, Token> tokenEnv, 
            Dictionary<string, Cube> cubeEnv
        ) {
            return new Result();
        }
    }
}
```

You can test it quickly [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/).

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't answer the question with regards to the error I'm asking about.

Comment: To clarify my last comment, I can see a different way to accomplish what I want with this answer, but it doesn't clarify on Func declarations giving an error if you define a certain number of parameters.

Comment: @OliverHare Then you must have some syntax error maybe? I edited my answer and provide example code that works without the `ref` parameters.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Sorry about the earlier confusion, I'm using VScode with the C# extension and it is throwing an error when ever I have a `Func<>` with more than 5 types, but testing your code, I see it still works when run. It must be an issue with the C# extension misinterpretting the syntax of a Func if it has too many parameters. Thanks.